# Protobuf for Python and protoc versions match still assertion fails

Tags: string, tensorflow, null, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am getting this error:

> ./google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h:86: const string&
>   google::protobuf::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(): Assertion
>   `empty_string_ != __null' failed.

I have been trying to fix this all day long.
So the flow in my project goes like this:

I have a C++ project that I compile using CMake on Ubuntu 16.10. After some processing I want to send the data to a Python script that uses Keras for machine learning.

Now both of these scripts work perfectly independently. I wanted to send the data directly to the Python script. So I have embedded Python in C++ by referring this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html)

This is again working for a Python script that does not import keras.

Now when I import keras in this Python script, I get the above error, though both of them work properly independetly.

First I had got an error for the mismatch of libprotobuf and protoc versions which looked like:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>   [libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:67] This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library,
>   but the installed version is 3.0.0.  Please update your library.  If
>   you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are
>   from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library. 
>   (Version verification failed in "google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc".)
>       terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
>         what():  This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 3.0.0.  Please
>   update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure
>   that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as
>   your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in
>   "google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc".)
>       Aborted (core dumped)

I had installed protoc using apt-get (latest available on apt-get is 3.0.0) as I found out on one of the answers that you need not have protoc 3.5.0 for it to work. `pip3 install protobuf` installs protobuf 3.5.0 which resulted in the mismatch error message.

So I uninstalled this Python protobuf version and installed the older version using `pip3 install protobuf==3.0.0`. This removed the mismatch error message.

But now I am getting the aforementioned error message. I have also figured out that the error message is occuring due to Tensorflow dependency of Keras

How do I fix this?

Please help